# Fire a AJAX request every second in AngularJS using $interval

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, setinterval

The interval function keeps on looping in the last element that I click. What I want to happen is to cancel the last interval when I click on a new element and start all over again when I click it. I clicking on each item in `ng-repeat`.

This is my code.

```
$scope.onClickTab= function(x,tkid, sid, $event){
      var vtpostdata = 'TokenId=' + tkid +
                                ',SessionId=' + sid +
                                ',ChatMessageCount=' + 0 +
                                ',retrytimes=' + 10 +
                                ',delayms=' + 100;
  $interval(function() {
      $http.jsonp(ServiceDomainSite + 'myApi' + vtpostdata + '?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&t=' 
                                    + new Date().getTime())
            .success(function (data) {
              var resultObject = angular.fromJson(data.Rows);
              $scope.Chats = resultObject;    
            });
  }, 1000);
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice and fine with `$interval.cancel()`. I also removed `var vtpostdata` because it is not used in the code untill your `$http` request again. So there is no need to create a var at this point. Also check the documentation of [AngularJS $interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) to learn more about $interval handling.

```
var myInterval = null;

$scope.onClickTab = function(x,tkid, sid, $event){

    //cancel current interval
    if (myInterval !== null) {
        $interval.cancel(myInterval);
    }

    myInterval = $interval(function() {
        $http.jsonp(ServiceDomainSite + 'myApiTokenId=' + tkid +
        ',SessionId=' + sid +
        ',ChatMessageCount=' + 0 +
        ',retrytimes=' + 10 +
        ',delayms=' + 100 + '?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&t='
        + new Date().getTime()).success(function (data) {
            var resultObject = angular.fromJson(data.Rows);
            $scope.Chats = resultObject;
        });
    }, 1000);
};
```

Comment: @JohnWick glad to help ya. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

`$interval` service returns a promise which can be canceled at any time so you can use them as per official documentation. For Eg.

```
var stopTime = $interval(function(){}, 1000);
```

and for canceling just use

```
$interval.cancel(stopTime);
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval